# Application not starting up due to postgres db drivers not found error

Tags: maven, cloudhub, mulesoft

Am trying to deploy mulesoft application thourgh maven to cloudhub. It got deployed successfully, but the application start up gives errors. I verified the POM file and dependency jars related to postgres and all were in place.

Please help to resole this issue

POM file

```
<sharedLibraries>
     <sharedLibrary>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
                            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                        </sharedLibrary>
                </sharedLibraries>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.2.5</version>
        </dependency>
```

Error:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Error trying to load driver: org.postgresql.Driver : Cannot load class 'org.postgresql.Driver': [
    org.postgresql.Driver, 
    Cannot load class 'org.postgresql.Driver': [
    Class 'org.postgresql.Driver' has no package mapping for region 'domain/default/app/loggingframework-app-dev'., 
    Cannot load class 'org.postgresql.Driver': [
    org.postgresql.Driver, 
    Class 'org.postgresql.Driver' not found in classloader for artifact 'container'.]]]
```

Comment: Depending on your version of Java you might need to set your version to `42.2.5.jre7` or `42.2.5.jre6`

Comment: Which version of Mule are you using?